# Adding extra coordinate axis to plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a plot just like the top one on page 9 in this [paper](https://www.nikhef.nl/~ivov/HiggsLectureNote.pdf).

[image]

I don't know how to add an extra set of coordinate axis, and tilt them accordingly. I would also like to be able to label the axis.

Here is my code so far:

```
F1 := Plot[(-x^2)/2 + (x^4)/4, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Black}]

F2 := Graphics[{Black, Thick, Dashed, Circle[{0, -0.25}, {1.0, 0.12}]}]

Show[F1, F2, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> Full, Axes -> {False, False}]
```

So I want a new set of coordinate axis with origin `(x,y)=(1,-0,25)`. I don't know if my code so far is the optimal way of doing what i am trying, but it works, and i understand why and how it works. I am very new to Mathematica so bear with me if this is an easy question. I have searched without luck for answers before asking this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Plot[-(x^2/2) + x^4/4, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.03}], 
 Ticks -> None, 
 Epilog -> {Arrowheads[0.03], Black, 
   Arrow[{{-0.25, -0.075}, {0.75, 0.225}}], Arrowheads[0.02], 
   Arrow[{{0.8, -0.25}, {1.5, -0.25}}], 
   Arrow[{{0.9, -0.35}, {1.2, -0.15}}], Dashed, 
   Circle[{0, -0.25}, {1., 0.12}], Line[{{-1, -0.25}, {-1, 0}}], 
   Text["-v", {-1, 0.05}], 
   Text["\!\(\*TagBox[SubscriptBox[\"ϕ\", \"1\"],\n \
DisplayForm]\)", {3, -0.1}], 
   Text["\!\(\*TagBox[SubscriptBox[\"ϕ\", \"2\"],\n \
DisplayForm]\)", {0.7, 0.3}], 
   Text[DisplayForm["v(Φ)"], {0.25, 0.95}], 
   Text["η", {1.6, -0.25}], 
   Text[DisplayForm["ε"], {1.1, -0.15}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: That was a very quick and perfect answer. Thank you very much! I am amazed by the efficiency of the mathematica stackexchange.